# Update Azure resource tags for multiple resources

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to update/change certain tags of multiple resources in our Azure environment. Using an example of a "Environment" tag and its value being spelled wrong as "Non-Prodd", the script will not work if there are multiple resources needing this update. I need this to update every resource with the incorrect tag value of "Non-Prodd" This is my script:

```
$r = (Get-AzResource -Tag @{Environment="Non-Prodd"}).Name
$tags = (Get-AzResource -Name $r).Tags 
$tags.environment = "Non-Prod" 
Get-AzResource -resourcename $r | Set-AzResource -Tag $tags -Force
```

Any input is appreciated for this PowerShell rookie!

Comment: you probably mean tag name, not value? or what part doesnt work exactly?

Comment: The tag is Environment and the value is Non-Prodd. If I want to change that value to Non-Prod for multiple resources, the above script doesn't work. It will only work if one resource has the incorrect tag value. The tag name will stay the same.

Comment: well, you are not changing tag name, so why would it change? as for the other part I still dont get it. I think you are doing filtering based on tag value with your first get-azresource, so this is expected

Comment: The scenario is I have about 50 resources with an incorrect tag value for the Environment tag. I am trying to update all of them with a script while preserving their current tags and their values.You are correct that I am trying to filter the resources based off the incorrect tag value. Then put their current tags in a variable, omitting the old Environment tag and then reapplying all tags including the new Environment tag. I was doing this in the portal but it became tiresome and wanted a handy script to do this whenever the situation presents itself.

Comment: well, if you can find the resources you are interested in based on some criteria this should be easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just modify the Tag value of Environment from "Non-Prodd" to "Non-Prod", pls try this :

```
$rs = get-azresource -TagName Environment

foreach($r in $rs){

    if($r.Tags.Environment -eq 'Non-Prodd'){
        $r.Tags.Environment = "Non-Prod"
        Set-AzResource  -ResourceId  $r.ResourceId -Tag $r.Tags -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Stanley. This is exactly what I have needed.

Comment: Welcome , have a nice day !