# Azure apply multiple tags to all resources under a specific Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to find out if its possible to apply multiple tags to all of the resources under a specific Resource Group in Azure. I don't know if this is possible because right now I am doing it manually via the Azure Portal but since our resources exploded I can't do it manually any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workaround is that you can add multiple tags to all the resources in you Resource Group through Powershell using [New-AzTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-aztag?view=azps-8.2.0). Below is the command that worked for me.

```
$tags = @{"<Tag1Name>"="<Value1>"; "<Tag2Name>"="<Value2>"}
$rs = get-azresource -ResourceGroup <Your_Resource_Group>
foreach($r in $rs){
   New-AzTag -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Tag $tags
}
```

In case if you are updating the Tag you can follow the answer suggested by [Stanley Gong  - Update Azure resource tags for multiple resources - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962737/update-azure-resource-tags-for-multiple-resources)

> ```
> $rs = get-azresource -TagName Environment
> foreach($r in $rs){
>   if($r.Tags.Environment -eq 'Non-Prodd'){
>      $r.Tags.Environment = "Non-Prod"
>        Set-AzResource  -ResourceId  $r.ResourceId -Tag $r.Tags -Force
>   }
> }
> ```

This can be also done in Azure CLI using [az tag create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/tag?view=azure-cli-latest#az-tag-create) apart from using Azure portal and powershell.

***REFERENCES:*** [Tag resources - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json#azure-cli)